# return statement with no value When trying to install cgpolyEncode in Python3.6

Tags: python, pip, python-3.6, google-polyline

My company is migrating from Python 2.7 to Python 3.6, and I'm trying to install cGPolyEncode. But this simply does not work, I get the error

```
 gpolyencode_py.cpp:187:69: error: ‘Py_InitModule3’ was not declared in this scope
                            "Google Maps Polyline encoding (C extension)");
                                                                         ^
    gpolyencode_py.cpp:190:9: error: return-statement with no value, in function returning ‘PyObject* {aka _object*}’ [-fpermissive]
             return;
             ^
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Every time. Some quick Googling seems to indicate that the module itself needs to be rewritten, which I am not qualified to do. I have already tried the basics of installing `python3.6-dev` `libxml2-dev` etc, but the issue remains. Is there a workaround or a way to install this without rebuilding it?

Answer (score 0):

C extensions are *quite different* between python2 and python3.  You *can* however write a file which satisfies both using the preprocessor.  Here's a sketch of a very basic C module [from my github](https://github.com/asottile/scratch/blob/6cdfe1e44f65fb2ae37ba67c3bc985d8d9a44ae1/python/basic_c_module.c):

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject* _hello_world(PyObject* self) {
    return PyUnicode_FromString("hello world");
}

static struct PyMethodDef methods[] = {
    {"hello_world", (PyCFunction)_hello_world, METH_NOARGS},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
static struct PyModuleDef module = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "basic_c_module",
    NULL,
    -1,
    methods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_basic_c_module(void) {
    return PyModule_Create(&module);
}
#else
PyMODINIT_FUNC initbasic_c_module(void) {
    Py_InitModule3("basic_c_module", methods, NULL);
}
#endif
```

Note that the `#else` branch is likely akin to what the current module has, you'll need to update it to look more like the `#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3` branch